# how to use the Laravel-OracleDB?

Tags: php, laravel, frame, lumen

I want to add the Laravel-OracleDB in the lumen,but I can't use the composer because my company can't use it.So I need to add the Laravel-OracleDB manually.But this is my first time to use the lumen or the laravel.
This is the address of the Laravel-OracleDB:
https://github.com/jfelder/Laravel-OracleDB;
And this is the folder list of the lumen:
[image: the folder list of lumen]

Comment: the Jfelder folder under the vendor is the laravel-oracleDB.

Comment: Why can't your company use it? Are you behind a proxy? It might be worth figuring out why it's not working for you rather than trying to manage dependencies yourself.

Comment: As @haakym already mentioned: You better sort out your composer problems. The requiremtents for Lumen clearly say: `Lumen utilizes Composer to manage its dependencies. So, before using Lumen, make sure you have Composer installed on your machine.` Maybe we can help you with your Composer problems?

Comment: My company is a big one.And it is a truth for us staff that our network can't  connect to the composer,I think it might be a proxy.Is there any way to solve this problem?